# Retrieve image through AJAX and display in img tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, image

How do I retrieve an image through javascript's AJAX and then show it in the img tag? FYI my image is saved as a BLOB. I've tried many solutions posted but it doesnt seem to work..

Here is my javascript ajax on BAConsult.php page.

```
function getimage(str,str1) { //get past consultation image and show in img tag 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {

        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","BAConsultGetImageAJAX.php?q="+str+"&q1="+str1,true);
    xmlhttp.send();   
}
```

This is my BAConsultGetImageAJAX.php page code.

```
$q = $_GET['q']; //get dateconsulted value
$q1 = $_GET['q1']; //get timeconsulted value
$consultimage="SELECT customerface FROM Counsel where nric='$_SESSION[nric]' and dateconsulted='$q' and timeconsulted='$q1'";
$consultimageresult = mysqli_query($dbconn,$consultimage);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultimageresult);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");


echo $row['customerface'];
```

Here is my img tag. I'm not sure what to put for the src.

```
<img id="customerface" src="" alt="your image" class ="consultimg">
```

Comment: why not just `<img src="script_that_gets_images_from_db.php?id=123">`?

Comment: @MarcB may i know what the id=123 refers to?

Comment: whatever your ID is for an image in the db.

Comment: Sorry but i know the ID for my image. I just save my image as blob in the database. How do i know the id of the image? you mean my image name like 20152231.jpg ?